# Facebook API re-showing user profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

Suppose a user gives my site permission to access their profile data.

Is it ok then if my site stores this data and then re-show it for view to other users on my site?

Note, my site would be explicit to the original user that this will occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed all parts of the profile that are public or that you have you permission to display, i am doing similar with page profiles @ http://AnotherFeed.com so far no issues with TOS or privacy.